# Every time Edge opens on my work computer it sets itself as default browser

Tags: windows, browser, file-association, microsoft-edge

Every time I start the Edge browser on my work computer it sets itself as default browser. This does not happen on my home computer, where Chrome stays the default browser even though I start Edge.

Is this some group policy that allows it to do this? Or what can I do to prevent this? No I'm avoiding starting Edge because I every time need to change Chrome back as the default browser.

Comment: Every time I start the Edge browser on my work computer it sets itself as default browser.   ...  Did the company implement a Group Policy to ensure Edge is Default?  You need to ask the Company about this.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. [Win]+[R] --> regedit --> [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter]
2. Browse to, or paste following path in "path bar" + [Enter] -->  Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge
3. Double click on "DefaultBrowserSettingEnabled"
4. Set value to 0 --> OK
5. Reboot PC

Comment: Hmm, does not seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall edge browser then download and install again when it ask make it default so cancel it and also check is it your [chrome set as default](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95417?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)

Comment: I can see three apps in the Add or Remove features: Microsoft Edge, Microsoft Edge Update, and Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime. The two first have the Uninstall button greyed out.

Comment: This answer is incomplete it suggests to until an application that cannot be uninstalled

Comment: In this case download edge browser manually and install it and select cancel on default browser ( after installation if is there any bug will be fix) [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge)

Comment: @SMith - The author is obviously running Windows 10 or Windows 11 and Edge is already installed.